# Separating the image background using openCV

Tags: image, opencv, background

Actually, I'm trying to subtract the background from this [image](http://goo.gl/sqFgTj). Apparently, I just want to subtract the green background and here is the code I'm using:

```
Mat img_object = imread(patternImageName);
Mat imageInHSV;
cvtColor(img_object, imageInHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);

Mat chan[3],imgThreshed, processed;
split( imageInHSV, chan );
Mat H = chan[0];
// compute statistics for Hue value
cv::Scalar mean, stddev;
cv::meanStdDev(H, mean, stddev);

// ensure we get 95% of all valid Hue samples (statistics 3*sigma rule)
float minHue = 80;
float maxHue = 95;
cout << "MinValue :" << mean[0] << " MaxHue:" << stddev[0] << endl;
cout << H << endl;
// STEP 2: detection phase
cv::inRange(H, cv::Scalar(minHue), cv::Scalar(maxHue), imgThreshed);
imshow("thresholded", imgThreshed);
```

I checked the values of the channel H to decide the minHue and maxHue so I choosed the interval of the most frequent values in the matrix which will definitely be the green one. But, I got this [result](http://goo.gl/8GJLhn) which is obsiously not what I'm looking for because there is missing stuff in it. Any idea how to improve it? how to get better subtract the background from this kind of images?

Comment: Where in the code did you use 'mean' and 'stddev' other that printing them?

Comment: I was using them but I got bad result so I tried to see the values and choose an interval of the most frequent values.

Comment: It seems that in your result image, you are showing (in white) the pixels that their hue is between 80 and 95. Is that right? If yes, what else you want to see in the result image? all background in white, while all other objects are in black?

Comment: The idea is only to try to get better results. As you can see in the result, it contains less information about the objects so we need to improve this part.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what your goal is. However, I got much better result on your sample image from the two other channels (Saturation and lightness rather than hue) using the range of `[mean-stddev,mean+stddev]`. Averaging the results of all three channels shows some improvement:

```
using namespace std ;
using namespace cv ;

int main()
{
    Mat img_object = imread("1.png");
    Mat imageInHSV;
    cvtColor(img_object, imageInHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);
    Mat chan[3];
    split( imageInHSV, chan );
    Mat result ;
    Mat threshImg[3] ;

    for(int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++)
    {
        Mat H = chan[i];

        // compute statistics for each channel
        cv::Scalar mean, stddev;
        cv::meanStdDev(H, mean, stddev);

        // statistically 68% of data should be in this range
        float minVal = mean[0]-stddev[0];
        float maxVal = mean[0]+stddev[0];
        cout << "MinValue :" << mean[0] << " MaxHue:" << stddev[0] << endl;

        // Separating the dominant 68% which we guess should be the background.
        cv::inRange(H, cv::Scalar(minVal), cv::Scalar(maxVal), threshImg[i]);
    }

    // averaging the results from three different channels (Hue, Saturation, lightness). 
    result = (threshImg[0]+threshImg[1]+threshImg[2])/3 ;
    imwrite("thresholded_012.jpg", result) ;
}
```

Input image:
[image]

Output image:
[image]

Comment: What I need exactly is to seperate the green background from the instruments. As you can see in your result, it is not very accurate so I'm looking for a strong algorithm that detects only the instrumetns